# Firebase React Native A/B Testing. How to get Firebase Instance ID tokens?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-ab-testing

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-with-console

This page shows only Native code. I can't find React Native / javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use React Native Firebase. Documentation states you can use A/B Testing with Remote Config, Cloud Messaging, or In-App Messaging. https://rnfirebase.io/remote-config/usage.

To get the Firebase Token, you can use the messaging package - https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#getToken